# Progress bar in jQuery when loading background-image from script

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, background-image, twitter-bootstrap, document-body

I have a script that loads big images into the body in this fashion :

```
$('body').css("background-image", "url(pics/jpg/folio/" + TtempID + ".jpg)");
```

I'm looking for a progress bar script that would run everytime the background image is changed, without a single page reload.

I'm currenty using Twitter BootStrap in conjonction with jQuery.

Thanks in advance for any valuable piece of information.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

**jQuery**

```
function loadBackground(image) {
    $('body').addClass('loading');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        $('body').css({
            'background-image': 'url(pics/jpg/folio/" + image + ".jpg)'
        }).removeClass('loading');
    };

    img.src = url;
}
```

**CSS**

```
.loading:after{
    content:' ';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:url('PATH-TO-LOADING-IMAGE') 50% 50% no-repeat;
    z-index:1000;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Use it like

```
    loadBackground( TtempID );
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CYFNc/2/

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind contribution. In the end, I decided to go for a easier route with the use of stacked layers with a gif animation instead of using the body element.